# Laravel Query with statements

Tags: mysql, laravel

This is a Query which converts data in rows, to data in columns, by declaring a variable then preparing the statement and executing the query.

**Now my question is how can i convert this query to laravel query format, kindly help me.**

`SET @sql = NULL, @sql1 = NULL, @sql2 = NULL;`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT('WHEN ''',  column_name, ''' THEN `', column_name, '`')
       SEPARATOR ' ')
  INTO @sql1
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA()
   AND table_name = '7'
   AND column_name LIKE '7%'
 GROUP BY table_name;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT('SELECT ''',  column_name, ''' objectid' )
       SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
  INTO @sql2
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA()
   AND table_name = '7'
   AND column_name LIKE '7%'
 GROUP BY table_name;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
'SELECT m.ObjectID, m.ObjectLabel, q.Value
  FROM modules_forms_objects m LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT objectid,
         CASE objectid ', @sql1, ' END value 
    FROM `7` t CROSS JOIN
  (', @sql2, '
  ) c
) q`enter code here`
    ON m.objectid = q.objectid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you cannot use raw queries?

`DB::select(' { Your Code Here} ');` ?

or
`DB::raw(' {Your Code Here} ');`

Comment: How about `DB::statement(' Your Code Here');`?

Comment: We need to see the error. If it says 'Syntax Error' then perhaps it is just the way your query is written? Please paste your query too.

Comment: All Friend thank you for the help, it solved by creating stored procedure.
Thank you Very Much.